# Multi Client Simple Chat(non-GUI) Server in Java using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I am unable to figure out how to stop the message from appearing twice on both the client's screen.

[image]

The Actual output should be something like this:
[image]

Steps for Running the code:
1. Run Server on one terminal
2. Run two clients on two different terminals

When I run the Server - main method creates a Server object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Server server = new Server();
    }
```

**Server Constructor:**

```
Server() throws IOException {
            Date dNow = new Date();
            System.out.println("MultiThreadServer started at " + String.format("%tc", dNow));
            System.out.println();

            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8000);
            ClientSockets = new Vector<Socket>();


            while (true) {
                    Socket client = server.accept();
                    AcceptClient acceptClient = new AcceptClient(client);
                    System.out.println("Connection from Socket " + "[addr = " + client.getLocalAddress() + ",port = "
                                    + client.getPort() + ",localport = " + client.getLocalPort() + "] at "
                                    + String.format("%tc", dNow));
                    System.out.println();
                    //System.out.println(clientCount);

            }
            //server.close();
    }
```

I am using Socket to connect to the server. Here is my Server code.
**Server.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Server {
    static Vector<Socket> ClientSockets;
    int clientCount = 0;
    //int i = 0;


    Server() throws IOException {
            Date dNow = new Date();
            System.out.println("MultiThreadServer started at " + String.format("%tc", dNow));
            System.out.println();

            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8000);
            ClientSockets = new Vector<Socket>();


            while (true) {
                    Socket client = server.accept();
                    AcceptClient acceptClient = new AcceptClient(client);
                    System.out.println("Connection from Socket " + "[addr = " + client.getLocalAddress() + ",port = "
                                    + client.getPort() + ",localport = " + client.getLocalPort() + "] at "
                                    + String.format("%tc", dNow));
                    System.out.println();
                    //System.out.println(clientCount);

            }
            //server.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Server server = new Server();
    }

    class AcceptClient extends Thread {
            Socket ClientSocket;
            DataInputStream din;
            DataOutputStream dout;

            AcceptClient(Socket client) throws IOException {
                    ClientSocket = client;
                    din = new DataInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream());
                    dout = new DataOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());

                    //String LoginName = din.readUTF();
                    //i = clientCount;
                    clientCount++;
                    ClientSockets.add(ClientSocket);
                    //System.out.println(ClientSockets.elementAt(i));
                    //System.out.println(ClientSockets.elementAt(1));

                    start();
            }

            public void run() {

                            try {
                                    while (true) {
                                    String msgFromClient = din.readUTF();
                                    System.out.println(msgFromClient);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < ClientSockets.size(); i++) {
                                            Socket pSocket = (Socket) ClientSockets.elementAt(i);
                                            DataOutputStream pOut = new DataOutputStream(pSocket.getOutputStream());
                                            pOut.writeUTF(msgFromClient);
                                            pOut.flush();
                                    }
                            }

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }

            }
    }
```

}

**Client.java**

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Client implements Runnable{

    Socket socketConnection;
    DataOutputStream outToServer; 
    DataInputStream din;


    Client() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

            socketConnection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8000);
            outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socketConnection.getOutputStream());
            din = new DataInputStream(socketConnection.getInputStream());


            Thread thread;
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();

            BufferedReader br = null;
            String ClientName = null;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String SQL = "";
            try {
                    System.out.print("Enter you name: ");
                    ClientName = input.next();
                    ClientName += ": ";
                    //QUERY PASSING

                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    while (!SQL.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.print(ClientName);

                            SQL = br.readLine();
                            //SQL = input.next();
                            outToServer.writeUTF(ClientName + SQL);
                            //outToServer.flush();
                            //System.out.println(din.readUTF());

                    }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
            Client client = new Client();
    }


    public void run() {
            while (true) {
                    try {
                            System.out.println("\n" + din.readUTF());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have this is because you're sending the server whatever the client has written in the console, and the server sends it back to **all** of the clients (**including the sender**).

So you're writing a message in the console (and you see it) and then you're receiving it back as one of the clients (and you see it again).

A simple fix would be not to send the just received message back to the client (he already sees it in the console). Add this to the `Server.AcceptClient#run` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ClientSockets.size(); i++) {
    Socket pSocket = (Socket) ClientSockets.elementAt(i);

    if(ClientSocket.equals(pSocket)){
        continue;
    }
    ...
```